# how to add html button on last index with token in the text box?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, c#-4.0

I want to add in the last index html button with token.
for example i have the three type token like test1,test2,test3 so in my text box show 3 token then i want to add button after "test3" token in the text box.
below my html code.

```html
<div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<div class="tokenfield form-control">
<div class="token">
<span class="token-label" style="max-width: 664px;">test1</span><a href="#" class="close" tabindex="-1">x</a>
  <span class="token-label" style="max-width: 664px;">test2</span><a href="#" class="close" tabindex="-1">x</a>
  <span class="token-label" style="max-width: 664px;">test3</span><a href="#" class="close" tabindex="-1">x</a>
</div>
</div>
     <input type="text" id="txttoken" class="full-width palintxtbx instagrowth_tokens" placeholder="entre" />                       
      </div>
```

Comment: Can you post what have you tried? To show effort you made, otherwise it looks like you want from somebody to solve you homework.

Comment: ok i will post my html code just waiting a few minutes.